How to paralleize/Vectorize PointCloud Histogram counting
I have a poitcloud tensor of shape [25,5600,3] which is in the form of [B,N,C] and a voxel grid size [25,32,32,32]. I am trying to get a normalized histogram (no of points) for each voxel. The following code uses PyTorch tensor manipulation, and works
def ptCld2VoxelGrid(self, point_cloud, min_coords, max_coords, grid_size):
    voxel_grid = torch.zeros((point_cloud.shape[0],grid_size, grid_size, grid_size), dtype=torch.float32)
    voxel_size = (max_coords - min_coords) / grid_size
    
    # Currently taking a lot of time. Need to parallelize
    voxel_indicesBatch = ((point_cloud - min_coords.unsqueeze(1)) / voxel_size.unsqueeze(1)).long()
    cond1 = (voxel_indicesBatch<grid_size)
    cond2 = (voxel_indicesBatch >= 0)
    cond = (cond1[:,:,0] & cond1[:,:,1] & cond1[:,:,2])&(cond2[:,:,0] & cond2[:,:,1] & cond2[:,:,2]) 


    
    for batch in tqdm(range(point_cloud.shape[0])):

        """
        # Calculate voxel indices for each point
        voxel_indices = ((point_cloud[batch,:,:] - min_coords[batch,:]) / voxel_size[batch,:]).long()

        x = (voxel_indices<grid_size)
        y = (voxel_indices >= 0)
        truth = (x[:,0] & x[:,1] & x[:,2])&(y[:,0] & y[:,1] & y[:,2])

        voxel_grid1 = torch.zeros((grid_size, grid_size, grid_size), dtype=torch.float32,device=voxel_indices.device)

        
        voxel_grid2 = torch.zeros((grid_size, grid_size, grid_size), dtype=torch.float32,device=voxel_grid.device)
        voxel_grid2[voxel_indicesBatch[batch,cond[batch]]] +=1 
        """

        for idx in tqdm(voxel_indicesBatch[batch,:,:]):
            if (idx >= 0).all() and (idx < grid_size).all():
                voxel_grid[batch,idx[0], idx[1], idx[2]] += 1
        

        # Normalize to create a probability distribution
        voxel_grid[batch,:,:] /= torch.sum(voxel_grid[batch,:,:])
    
    return voxel_grid

As you can notice in the commented section of the code, I tried to vectorize as much as possible, but voxel_grid2[voxel_indicesBatch[batch,cond[batch]]] +=1  isn't giving the same sum as the output of the loop. Currently the loop takes about 12secs/batch (not sure why). Is there something I can do to vectorize the whole thing or at-least speed it up x10?
Any help is greatly appretiated.
